# how to disable an input with a checkbox JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a webpage that is supposed to ease the writing of code for another program (Ren'Py), and I made it in a way that there is a button that adds 3 inputs (checkbox, text, text).
Now I wanted to make it so that the first input is disabled and will only enable when the checkbox is checked.

I have looked at many other questions just like this, but none seemed to help, I made a fiddle of the code working in a static run, so where the code is already there. But It should work for all of them, even if there is a new one added.

```js
var i = 0 //the variable is for a later cause, doesn't affect this, isn't implemented yet
function addDialogue() {
 ++i
 var poseLine = '<input type="checkbox" id="poseBox' + i + '" class="pose" />\n<input id="pose' + i + '"  />'
 var text = '<input id="text' + i + '" >'
 var breaker = '<br />'
 var line = poseLine + text + breaker
 $( "#dialogeAndCode" ).append( line )
}

function main () {
 console.log( "JQuery has loaded" )
 $( ":checkbox" ).change( function() {
  if ( $( this ).hasClass( "pose" ) ) {
   $( this ).next().prop( "disabled", !$( this ).is( ':checked' ) );
  }
 } );
}

$( document ).ready( main );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="buttonAddText" value="Add a dialoge line" onclick="addDialogue();">
<br />
<div id="dialogeAndCode">
</div>
```

and here's the static run (JS Fiddle): https://jsfiddle.net/DiamondFrost/1dsdd2Lx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are adding the checkboxes dynamically to the DOM

they are not existent while parsing your main function, to do this dynamically

instead of

```
$( ":checkbox" ).change( function() {
```

try

```
$(document).on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
```

Comment: Thank you it now is working

Comment: you´re welcome, common pitfall, will never happen to you again, answered thousand times, feel free to accept as answer ;-)

Comment: I will once I can (still have the timer thing)

Answer (score 1):

The checkboxes don't exist at the time that you are setting up the event handler, so set it up on the `document` and use **[JQuery's event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)** so that checkboxes that get created in the future will be picked up.

Additionally, JQuery deprecated the `.change()` method some time ago and says to just use the `.on()` method for all event binding.

Lastly, set the text fields to be `disabled` by default because your checkboxes are not checked by default.

```js
var i = 0 //the variable is for a later cause, doesn't affect this, isn't implemented yet
function addDialogue() {
 ++i
  // Set the textbox to be disabled by default
 var poseLine = '<input type="checkbox" id="poseBox' + i + '" class="pose">\n<input disabled id="pose' + i + '">'
 var text = '<input id="text' + i + '" >'
 var breaker = '<br />'
 var line = poseLine + text + breaker
 $( "#dialogeAndCode" ).append( line )
}

function main () {
 console.log( "JQuery has loaded" )
  
  // Set up the event on the document, but trigger it if the source of it
  // was a checkbox
 $(document).on("change", "input[type=checkbox]", function() {
  if ( $( this ).hasClass( "pose" ) ) {
   $( this ).next().prop( "disabled", !$( this ).is( ':checked' ) );
  }
 } );
}

$( document ).ready( main );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="buttonAddText" value="Add a dialoge line" onclick="addDialogue();">
<br />
<div id="dialogeAndCode">
</div>
```